# Python dataframe not updating

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
date    event   ticker  initialprice120 initialprice90  initialprice60  initialprice30  initialprice7   finalprice
0   2010-11-18  MELA Mela Sciences FDA Panel            MELA    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   2010-12-07  OREX Orexigen Therapeutics Inc PDUFA    OREX    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   2010-12-07  SLXP SALIX PHARMACEUTICALS LTD PDUFA    SLXP    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   2010-12-09  HGSI HUMAN GENOME SCIENCES INC PDUFA    HGSI    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   2010-12-16  AZN Astrazeneca PDUFA                   AZN 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

and I would like to retrieve for each row the stock price for that exact date and for one week before that date, i wrote this code it s working fine and i see it s assigning values to initialprice120, initialprice90 etc, but not updating the cells of the dataset in the end, that is if a print fda.head() the price rows are still 0.0:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
for index, row in fda1.iterrows():
  try:
    ticker=row['ticker']
    print(ticker)
    end_date=row['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    start_date120=row['date'] - timedelta(days=120)
    start_date120=start_date120.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
    data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date=start_date120, 
                                                  end_date=end_date, 
                                                  time_interval='daily')
    aapl_df = pd.DataFrame(data[ticker]['prices'])
    initialprice120=float(aapl_df.iloc[0,4])
    initialprice30=float(aapl_df.iloc[20,4])
    initialprice60=float(aapl_df.iloc[40,4])
    initialprice90=float(aapl_df.iloc[60,4])
    initialprice7=float(aapl_df.iloc[78,4])
    finalprice=float(aapl_df.iloc[len(aapl_df)-1,4])
    row['finalprice']=float(finalprice)
    row['initialprice120']=float(initialprice120)
    row['initialprice30']=float(initialprice30)
    row['initialprice60']=float(initialprice60)
    row['initialprice90']=float(initialprice90)
    row['initialprice7']=float(initialprice7)
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: Replace `row['initialprice120']` with `fda1.at[index, 'initialprice120']`

Answer (score 0):

See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html for operations on series.

To access a single value by a label use `row.at[label] = ...`
or `fda1.at[index, label] = ...`